# Using Case Statement to check multiple fields and return first matched true value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

There are ten checkboxes on a form. When the form is completed I would like to know the result using a query in SSRS. The checboxes each have different names Checkbox1, Checkbox2, Checkbox3...with values of Yes when checked, and NULL uncheck. I want to calculate how many individual responses I received with one or more (multiple) checkboxes were checked off. How can I find out when multiple checkboxes are selected?

```
sum (case when Checkbox1='Yes' Or Checkbox2='Yes' 
Or Checkbox3='Yes' Or Checkbox4='Yes' Or Checkbox5='Yes' 
Or Checkbox6='Yes' Or Checkbox7='Yes' Or Checkbox8='Yes' 
Or Checkbox9='Yes' Or Checkbox10='Yes' then 1 else 0 end) checkboxresult
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the checkbox value to a numeric value of 1 or 0 then you can sum them to see if the total is more than one, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  ResponseID
 ,CASE 
    WHEN SUM(Checkbox1+Checkbox2+Checkbox3+Checkbox4+Checkbox5
                +Checkbox6+Checkbox7+Checkbox8+Checkbox9+Checkbox10) > 1
        THEN 'Multiple responses'
        ELSE 'Zero or 1 responses'
  END ResponseType
FROM
(
SELECT
   ResponseID
  ,CASE Checkbox1 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox1
  ,CASE Checkbox2 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox2
  ,CASE Checkbox3 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox3
  ,CASE Checkbox4 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox4
  ,CASE Checkbox5 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox5
  ,CASE Checkbox6 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox6
  ,CASE Checkbox7 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox7
  ,CASE Checkbox8 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox8
  ,CASE Checkbox9 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox9
  ,CASE Checkbox10 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Checkbox10
FROM
  <SomeTable>
) Responses
```